# IIS logs show much longer duration than Insights

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0, azure-application-insights

I have a `Web API` application hosted under an on-prem (not Azure) IIS which logs to Insights and is showing `Request` durations very similar to the times reported in the IIS logs.

However, every so often, there is an entry in the IIS logs with a `TimeTakenMS` duration which is much longer than the Insights `Request` duration.

For example, a relatively simple request to read a small amount of data from the DB is logged with a total duration by Insights as `984.126ms` but IIS is logging it with `TimeTakenMS` as `43718`.

I have conclusively linked the two requests (they show a unique URL). I have eliminated application start up/recycle times (the application is clearly already started and serving other requests and the [recycle boundary is hours away from the logged time stamps](https://support.secureauth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019884311-How-to-enable-Application-Pool-recycle-logging-)) and I have eliminated exceptions (Insights is not logging any exceptions at this time).

I also have a `StopWatch` set up in the controller for every web method and `TrackTrace` the elapsed milliseconds to Insights in a `finally` block, just before the method returns.

What other factors could cause an IIS hosted application to fail to log actual execution times to Insights but cause IIS to log much longer times?

I've considered [network + processing time](https://rothmanshore.com/2011/04/22/performance-yes-time-taken-in-iis-includes-network-time/), but 42 seconds seems an unreasonably long duration (even for the start up time of this particular application.)

Comment: I don't know much about Insights in Azure. But 42 seconds really too long in IIS log. As we all know, when IIS receives a request, many modules need to process the request, such as MIME, Handler Mappings, URL Rewrite... and then the request will be processed by the Asp.net application. But it will not take long. I think the possibility of being affected by this is very small. The network is indeed a factor that affects time-taken, and you don't have a good way to rule it out. I think you can enable failed request tracing. It will specifically record the time for each module.

Comment: Sorry, the IIS in question is on-prem, not in Azure. I have clarified this in the post.

Comment: Yes, I know. So I think you can check how long IIS takes for each module to process the request in FRT log.

Comment: Wasn't sure what that was, but googled and found this: https://stackify.com/beyond-iis-logs-find-failed-iis-asp-net-requests/

Comment: Failed request tracing is a more useful way to trouble shooting than IIS error log. You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) about failed request tracing.